# As administrator, get access token on behalf of another user

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm trying to implement IdentityServer4. We need to functionality to login as another user, when we're administrators.

I've already setup the login functionality for regular users, but I'd like a specific endpoint where an administrator can enter the username/id of a regular user.

How would one go about implementing this in IdentityServer4, as well as regular oauth2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is outside the scope of OIDC/OAuth2 interactions but there are some conventions for how to respresent such a scenario in the result token/claims. Have a read of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693 (in particular the `act` claim bits) for some inspiration.

We did this via the sign in UI flow but the model was that users could grant other users impersonation permissions explicitly. If when signing in you had valid impersonation grants then you'd be prompted as part of the sign in flow to choose a different account or continue as yourself. In your case you can identify admin users and give them the option to impersonate anyone you like.

If the user choses an impersonatee then it would change the current session to respresent that user but also store claims relating to the original user/session in the actor claim (`act`) and also add an `amr` claim of `imp`. We then made these claims available to clients so that they'd be aware of the fact impersonation was used and could then for example add that info to audit logs etc. We also notify the impersonated user via email and restrict access to account settings - i.e. impersonators can only sign into clients as other users, they cannot change their account settings.

Comment: I understand that the `act` claim can be used for impersonation, but I'm unaware as to how I should implement this using IdentityServer4.

Comment: The sign in flow itself it kind of outside the scope of IdentityServer4 and you can implement that however you like. I think I did modify some of the IDS4 services however to ensure that certain claims were presented how i wanted (i.e. that the JSON fragment stored in `act` was returned in the correct format from the authorize and token endpoints. I can probably dig out some examples if you can provide me with specifics.

Comment: I would love some examples. It's a bit difficult for me to give you any specifics though. I just find it strange that there's no sample out there showing this particular feature. I get the fact that it's not necessarily the responsibility of IDS4, but it's an auth server non-the-less, and this feature is especially helpful when we (the developers) want to see the application in-use as the specific user that may have an issue. IDS4 have many classes and interfaces that I can inherit/derive from, but I'm finding it difficult as to where this functionality should be placed.

Comment: I'm also well aware that I'm basically asking this community as well as the creators of IDS4 to just give me the code so this works :) But I'm somewhat at a loss here, and desperately looking for a solution.

Comment: I think my main point of guidance would be that you are in full control of what claims get stored in the authentication cookie that drives all of this and are free to change them at any point based on any user interaction you like. The `identityserver4` `authorize` endpoint will use the information present in that cookie to drive the tokens returned.

Comment: I completely get what you mean, and I understand the principles of it. I've already taken contro0l of the claims in my `/External/Challenge` and ´/External/Callback´ endpoints of IDS4, but I'm still having some issues with my `AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator`. This however, is beyond the scope of this SO, and I'm thinking of creating a new SO to target this specific issue that I'm having. I want to thank you for your guidance, your help is appreciated :) I'm going to mark your answer as the answer to the SO, as it describes what needs to be done.